# GAE - Storing multiple OAuth access token

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, oauth, google-cloud-datastore

For a project I am working on I need to store the user access token (and auth code and refresh token I assume).
I am using GAE for this and I have difficulties to design the model, which is quite simple. I have no experience with NoSQL so the GAE datastore is troubling.

Here is the global architecture of the project

```
Android Mobile --- Python Server --- GAE Python Server
   |_______________________________________|
```

The user will register through the android application via the GAE server using their google account and OAuth. Then I think I should create a user object with the user_id retrieved via GAE.

Afterwards I want the user to enable my application to access some Cloud storage services (Drive, Box, Dropbox, ...).
Once he does that, I will have the three token relative to this service and user and I need to store them somehow.

What would be the best way of storing Oauth credentials for multiple services relative to a single user in GAE datastore?

From what I have read, i could use Expando class and add service by service to the User Entity, or do a separate entity and stores them using References and a List in the User Entity,...
The most relevant piece of information [GAE Credential Storage](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine#Storage). But how could I use this for multiple services, and thus credentials ?

I thank you all for your help

----EDIT------------------------------

It seems I didn't have the good keywords for doing research on the subject.
After a few more hours:
[GAE - Google Developer - Modeling Entity Relationships](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling)

```
class User(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class ServiceOAuthAccess(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
  service_name = db.StringProperty(choices=('Dropbox', 'Box', 'Drive'))
  ....
```

But still, I have a quetion left:

Can I store any service's OAuth tokens using `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential`?
Or is it Google specific?

Also using this, I won't use `AppEngineCredentialStore`. Would it be better if I do? Is there anyway I could use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I didn't have the good keywords for doing research on the subject. After a few more hours: [GAE - Google Developer - Modeling Entity Relationships](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling)

```
class User(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()

class ServiceOAuthAccess(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
  service_name = db.StringProperty(choices=('Dropbox', 'Box', 'Drive'))
  ....
```